# Externalize settings within Amazon Web Servises

Tags: amazon-web-services

What the preffered way to externalize settings with Amazaon Web Services?

The goal is to be possible to change, for ex., db connection url for runned application across all instances an single point.

I have EC2 and BeanStalk instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

1. Custom Shell scripts
2. Capistrano
3. [Opscode Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)
4. [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com)

and many such other tools can be used. Amazon's own OpsWorks uses Chef.

Comment: Lets clurify a bit. I have Spring applications and I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. So I will have access to properties' values everywhere in App. I'll have embedded inJar properties but it is neccessery to have possibility to override these values centralized. Are there some simpler way than this frameworks?